openapi dart generator problem with schema attribute of type array
The following JSON file serves to illustrate the problem:
{
  "openapi" : "3.0.1",
  "info" : {
    "title" : "api_test",
    "version" : "1.0.0"
  },
  "paths" : {
  },
  "components" : {
    "schemas" : {
      "Obj1" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "mode" : {
            "uniqueItems" : true,
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "enum" : [ "mode1", "mode2", "mode3" ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Obj2" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "properties" : {
          "mode" : {
            "uniqueItems" : true,
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "enum" : [ "mode1", "mode2", "mode3" ]
            }
          }
       }
      }
   }
  }
}

I used the following statement to generate the code.
openapi-generator generate -g dart -i api_test.json -o "$(pwd)/api_test" --additional-properties=pubName=api_test

My problem is that in the class Obj1 the property mode is declared as follows.
  Set<Obj1ModeEnum> mode;

While in the same file (obj1.dart) the following class is defined:
class Obj2ModeEnum {
  /// Instantiate a new enum with the provided [value].
  const Obj2ModeEnum._(this.value);
  ...

In the obj2.dart file, the mode property is then declared as follows:
Set<ModeEnum> mode;

Here the corresponding enum is defined again under the same name.
class Obj2ModeEnum {
  /// Instantiate a new enum with the provided [value].
  const Obj2ModeEnum._(this.value);

Is this an error in the dart generator or is the JSON faulty?
